# Get the name of the link in the where clause of php query when I click the link?

Tags: php

I have made a website in which the users can select a value from a dropdown menu and get some information from a database. I used ajax to send the request to the database (so the page doesn't get refreshed when I send the request). Here is the part of the jquery function:

```
      $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'activities_code.php',
      data: {datastr:datastr, datastr1:datastr1},
      success:function(response){

        $("#msg").html(response);                           
            }});}); // there are other functions before..
```

The results appear on the main container of the webpage. They are composed of a title and some text. I echo the title in such a way so it is a link. I also give to each  element an id and a class so I can call it later. Here is the corresponding code:

```
    echo "<table id=\"container\">";
$num_results = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     // Here the columns of title and information are printed
     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo "<a href='test.php' name=\"fd\" id=\"t".$t."\" target=\"_new\"  class='pickanchor' onClick=\"test()\">".$row['title']."</a>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo $row['PK'];
     echo "</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['Information'];
     echo "</td></tr>"; 
 }
```

What I am trying to do now is: When I click on the title (which is a link), a new page to open in which a php script runs a query and show more information:
Here is what I have:

```
     <?php
     include('connect.php');


    $query = "SELECT title,Information from activities where title='?????'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('no available data');
echo "<table>";
$num_results = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     // Here the columns of title and information are printed
     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo "<a href='test.php' id=\"t\".$t target=\"_new\">".$row['title']."    </a>";
     echo "</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td>";

     echo $row['Information'];

     echo "</td></tr>";
    // Here I sum up the number of the results
     $num_results=$num_results+1;        
 }
     ?>
```

I am trying to find a way to put in my query, in the where clause, the name of the title that I selected:

```
     $query = "SELECT title,Information from activities where title='?????'";
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if everything is clear or I didn't explain some point clearly.
Thanks.
D.

Comment: Do an onclick function with $.post(url?title=$('.title').val())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the **title** using `$_GET` global variable and URL parameter. Try changing this line:

```
echo "<a href='test.php' name=\"fd\" id=\"t".$t."\" target=\"_new\"  class='pickanchor' onClick=\"test()\">".$row['title']."</a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='test.php?title={$row['title']}' name=\"fd\" id=\"t".$t."\" target=\"_new\"  class='pickanchor' onClick=\"test()\">".$row['title']."</a>";
```

then you can get the title with these code:

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
```

make sure you sanitize the value first. I hope this will help you.

**link:**

[PHP $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly! I am new in php and I am not sure what you mean with sanitizing. Can you give me a hint? Thanks again.